# Intellij reformat breaks scss default for variables

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, reformat

I am using IntelliJ Idea and have problems using "Ctrl + Alt + L" reformatting inside SCSS or SASS files.

I declare variables with:
`$myvariable: 15px !default;`

But the reformat function brings unwanted whitespace:
`$myvariable: 15px ! default;`

How can I tell the reformat feature to skip "!default".

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using an old PhpStorm or IntelliJ IDEA version that still has this bug.
I've tried with [PhpStorm 5.0.2](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/index.html) and cannot reproduce this problem.

Note that current IDEA 11.1.3 release also has this problem, but [IDEA 12 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP) works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have this problem at IDEA 11.1.3, maybe I'll download 12EAP now because its very annoying.